# Reducing code in ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, angularjs

I relatively new to AngularJS, and also brushing up on my JS in the process, so this may come across as a very basic question, but here goes nothing. I would like to separate my code out, i.e. the logic from the presentation, since I would like to follow the MVC guidelines.

So, the problem I have is that I end up having to write a lot of code in my HTML, and I really do not like this since, it gets hard to debug later on, and this code is included inside `ng-repeat`.

So, without much further-ado, here is the code, for reference, I please [check this](https://dpaste.de/HWewy/#L22,23), as it has line numbers to the side.:

**HTML**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en-US" ng-app>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>ng-click</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" media="all"/>
</head>
    <body>
    <!--Search div-->
    <div class="search">
        <label for="findName" >
            Find your name:
            <input type="search" name="userSearch" id="angularUserSearch" ng-model="search"/>
        </label>
    </div>

    <!--List of results-->
    <div ng-controller="List">
        <ul>
            <!--Can also work with objects-->
            <li ng-repeat="person in people | filter:search">
                {{ person.name }} -> {{ person.age }}
            </li>
        </ul>
        <div>
            <label for="">
                Name:
                <input type="text" name="new_name" id="new_name" ng-model="new_name"/>
            </label>
            <br>
            <label for="">
                Age:
                <input type="text" name="new_age" id="new_age" ng-model="new_age"/>
            </label>
            <br>
            <button ng-click="add()">Add</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!--Scripts-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="angular_1.0.7.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="myscript.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

The styling is irrelevant. So, I leave it out.

**JavaScript**

```
var List = function ($scope) {
    // Making the list called names
    $scope.people = [
        {name: "Harold", age:"20"},
        {name: "Jessie", age:"34"},
        {name: "Samantha", age:"18"},
        {name: "March", age:"40"},
        {name: "Scott", age:"44"},
        {name: "David", age:"28"},
        {name: "Dan", age:"28"}
    ];

    $scope.add = function () {
        $scope.people.push({
            name: $scope.new_name,
            age: $scope.new_age
        });
        $scope.new_name = "";
        $scope.new_age = "";
    };
};
```

So, what I would like to do, is simply give `ng-repeat` (on line 22) a function, that is declared in my JS, so that I do not have to put in any business logic inside the code. So for example, I would like something like this:

```
 <li ng-repeat="function_that_returns_person_objects()">
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It makes sense to put page logic on the template like the comprehension expression in the `ng-repeat`. This is not the business logic, it is the logic for rendering the page. And it is more elegant than implementing it using an function.

`ng-repeat` only takes an expression but you should be able to use a function as a part of the expression like this,

```
<li ng-repeat="data in myFunction()">
```

so you can simplify a bit if you need to preprocess the data source. But I don't think you can use a pure function in the `ng-repeat` as what you said. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you so much for answering my questions, you've been a great help the past few days, but a pure function is what I want, since I want to abstract away the logic, it just makes for easier debugging, thats all, and if I wanted to re-use the code, then that makes better sense too. Also, when filters get more complicated than this, I'd like to know how to abstract that away as a function.

Comment: @GamesBrainiac It seems Angularjs doesn't support it according to the doc.http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngRepeat

Comment: I see... well then, guess thats it. Thanks man! :D I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite understand why you need the `function_that_returns_person_objects` again. Angular's binding will take care of ensuring your view stays up to date.

Here's a [demonstration](http://embed.plnkr.co/cxbP5xdgSHFHv7aqBqRf/preview), and here's the [source](http://plnkr.co/edit/cxbP5xdgSHFHv7aqBqRf) for it.

Comment: My goal is to simply abstract away the logic. Thats what I intend to do.

Comment: I've removed the extra logic from ng-click now.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a complex filter function then just write it 'aside' like this : http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/dev_guide.templates.filters.creating_filters

But when you **consume it**, it's right from the view, as you want to repeat an view partial following the value returned by it.